# link or button mouseover pop-upbox/image location change

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mouseover

I have a text box(link) that is currently linked to be a mouseover popup image however the popup appears right at the mouseover location. I need this to be changed to a specific location. How do I change the location of where the popup appears? Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" onmouseover="ShowImage('http://ultimatefinishdetailing.com/images/vancombination4.jpg')" onmouseout="HideImage()">Ultimate Finish Auto Detailing</a>

<img id="popupImage" src="" alt="Popup image" style="display: none"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowImage(src)
{
    var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
    img.src = src;
    img.style.display = "block";
}
function HideImage()
{
    document.getElementById('popupImage').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a div

```
<div class="pop-up">

   <img id="popupImage" src="" alt="Popup image" style="display: none"/> 
</div>
```

The apply the css to div as per your needs

```
 .pop-up {
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;
  top : 30px;
  left : 25px;
  float : right;
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khv4p/)</kbd>

Comment: Added a fiddle for example

Comment: ok...so add the css and div's....got it...i will need to try this before I'm confident to say it works perfectly. also. I was wrong about the multiple links for the same image....what I meant was I have multipe text strings that I need to link to different images. complicated.....

Comment: No you are already passing the image url on whichever link you over. So you just need to align the wrapper div as per your needs. See **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/T5V9y/)**

Comment: oh i see! nice. thx. i will finish the code for the particulars and let you know if I have any issues. you da man!

Comment: ok. so i put the codes in on my yahoo sitebuilder but the pic isn't moving. I don't know where to put the css code. I tried in the html and the html element but nothing happened. Where do I put the CSS?

Comment: yea...apparently i have to go straight html and no css...unless there's a way to put in the css. I need help....

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out how to put the css into the html element by ebedding the css into the html. (I heard this way is a little slower than having a downloaded css file but I don't know how to do that yet) Anyway, this gives me another problem. I cannot have multiple links with this on my page because the elements expand ontop of other html elements; so I can't even see anything. So the fix is to have two html elements that link to eachother. one that's stationary for a popup for all the links and the other html element links addressing that stationary one...i dont know how to do this either